# Scanner for MSbuild mandatory parameters in SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

By any chance is there a way to have all the mandatory parameters such as project key , project name and version in SonarQube.Analysis.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

`SonarQube.Analysis.xml` is the global scanner configuration. If you are analyzing several solutions you'll share the same scanner installation. That's why putting projectKey/version/name in `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` would not be a good idea.
Note that starting from SonarQube 6.1 + Scanner for MSBuild 2.2 (should be released soon), project name and version are now optional.